# Is there any good software to remotely take photos of someone who has stolen my macbook?

Tags: macos, mac, security, webcam

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of an app I could install on my macbook pro that would allow me to photograph someone who has stolen it and receive their photo when they connect to the internet. I realise there would be difficulties with this (a solution with a centrally based server would probably be necessary to do this best) but I'd be very interested to know if something like this exists. My searches have not found exactly what I'm after (eg iAlertU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock Down http://www.foozoodesign.com/lockdown.html

Undercover http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/

or the MobileMe service with Back to My Mac can be used to accomplish what you want.
http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/mac.html

Comment: Happy Undercover user here.

Comment: Undercover looks like it'll do exactly what I want. MobileMe has always been a bit of a turn-off for me - for the price it doesn't do much that I can't already do for free elsewhere. The one-off cost of Undercover seems pretty reasonable for what it does. I've purchased a licence for my computer and my wife's. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [VUWER](http://stumpy.vuse.vanderbilt.edu/VUWER.htm) which is an open source recovery tool written in applescript.

It can give you screenshots, isight images and IP address info either using Google’s free email and web services or using a remote computer account with scp.

If you follow the additional 'securing your computer' steps you will have a pretty secure Mac with a remote recovery option if the theif connects to the internet.

Comment: And it's a dumb thief. Or at least not smart.